# I cant get the ionic autocomplete to work with

Tags: angularjs, cordova, autocomplete, ionic-framework

I am using [guylabs/ion-autocomplete](http://guylabs.ch/project/ionic-autocomplete/#template-url) but facing some problems when running it in the ios and android emulator. Beforehand I made a mockup running it in the browser and this worked fine, but when copying the same code to my actual project I got an error. Could someone please help me.. dont have any clue!

The following error I got in the console:
[Error] Error: collection-repeat expected attribute collection-item-height to be a an expression that returns a number (in pixels) or percentage.

HTML

```
<div class="list card">
    <ion-autocomplete 
        ng-model="model"
        item-value-key="view"
        item-view-value-key="name"
        item-view-value-key="id"
        items-method="getTestItems(query)"
        items-method-value-key="items"
        items-clicked-method="itemsClicked(callback)"
        select-items-label="SEARCH"
        selected-items-label="Selected:"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
tcControllers.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $localStorage) {
$localStorage.getObject('Something').forEach(function(ticket){
    if (ticket.id == parseInt($stateParams.ticketId)){
        $scope.ticket = ticket;
    }
});
$scope.model = "";
$scope.callbackValueModel = "";
$scope.getTestItems = function (query) {
    var zoekItems = [
        {id: "1", name: "John", view: "John: "},
        {id: "2", name: "Richard", view: "Richard: "},
        {id: "3", name: "Steve", view: "Steve: "},
    ];
    var returnValue = { items: [] };
    zoekItems.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
        if (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
            returnValue.items.push(item);
        }
        else if (item.id.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
            returnValue.items.push(item);
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
};
$scope.itemsClicked = function (callback) {
    $scope.callbackValueModel = callback;
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `collection-repeat` directive that autocomplete is using. It's probably best to update to the latest stable Ionic version (1.0.0) which will resolve this issue. You can also go into lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.js and add `collection-item-height="52"` in place of `item-height` (line 88) and it should work, but I would recommend updating.

Comment: This is the solution for the problem. Ionic changed some things in the `collection-repeat` and updating to `1.0.0.rc3` or later should fix it. ion-autocomplete `0.2.1` is using `1.0.0.rc3` as ionic version. The related github issue is this one: https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete/issues/21

Comment: Note that earlier versions of 1.0.0 do not work.  I was on ionic 1.0.0-beta14, and this issue still existed.  I upgraded to rc3, and it has been resolved.

Comment: many thanks!! I used $ ionic lib update and updated to rc5 and it works great!!